# Average-case error and worst-case error in entangment-assisted classical communication

Tags: entanglement, information-theory, communication

I am reading [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1405.1797.pdf) where one considers a quantum channel $\mathcal{N}$. We are interested in the maximum rate at which we can send classical messages over this channel in the one-shot setting i.e. Alice and Bob only get to use a finite number of copies of the channel. Alice and Bob may use shared entanglement to help them in their task. The following sentence is from the paper

> Let $\log M_{\rm ea}(N^n, \varepsilon)$ denote the maximum number of
> bits of information that can be transmitted through $n$ uses of the
> channel via an entanglement-assisted communication protocol, such that
> the average probability of failure is no larger than
> $\varepsilon\in(0,1)$

The "average probability of failure" is defined in (2.3) of the paper and I explain it below.

Let $M$ be a random variable that takes on values $m$ from some set of messages $\mathcal{M}$. The random variable $M$ is obtained by choosing a uniformly random message from the set of messages $\mathcal{M}$. Let Bob decode to random variable $M'$. Suppose there exists some encoder and decoder such that $\text{Pr}(M\neq M')\leq \varepsilon$.

**Question**

My question is why the authors talk only about the average-case error and not the worst-case error. The worst-case error would be the error in transmitting some specific message $m\in\mathcal{M}$ instead of looking at the random variable $M$. But since Alice and Bob have access to free entanglement, they have free shared randomness. Let Alice apply a random permutation $\Pi$ on the set of messages, let Alice and Bob execute the protocol and then let Bob apply $\Pi^{-1}$ to the output. In this case, isn't it true that

$$\text{Pr}(m \neq m') \leq \varepsilon.$$

My reasoning is as follows: If we want to send the message $m$, the probability of error is
$$\text{Pr}(m \neq m') = \sum_{\hat{m}\in\mathcal{M}}\text{Pr}(\Pi(m) = \hat{m})\times \text{Pr}(\hat{m}\neq \hat{m}') = \frac{1}{|\mathcal{M}|}\sum_{\hat{m}\in\mathcal{M}}\text{Pr}(\hat{m}\neq \hat{m}') \leq \varepsilon$$

That is, the random permutation means that the probability of an error on a specific message $m$ is the probability of the permutation selecting $\hat{m}$ as the message to apply the protocol on multiplied by the probability of making an error in transmitting $\hat{m}$ summed over all $\hat{m}$. This has to be the same for every message.

Thus, the average-case error of $\varepsilon$ implies that the worst-case error can also be bounded to $\varepsilon$. Is there a flaw in the argument?